# Is there a method to change the passwords new users receive via email in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website with WooCommerce Subscriptions and Memberships.

New users on my website receive an email with their username and password. The password inside this email is 12 characters long and contains a mix of characters. Is there a way to do any of the following:

1. Change default password character length
2. Change default password to equal customer's lastname + 1 (e.g Hua1)
3. Change the default password to only contain (a-z, 0-9)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: "receive an email with their username and password"  Is this the default behavior of WooCommerce??  That is ... quite concerning.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of WordPress, not WooCommerce afaik.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very likely that one of your plugins is overriding the default wp_new_user_notification() function with a less secure version.

If you look in wp-includes/pluggable.php, you'll note that in WP 4.3 the function was changed to remove the plaintext parameter, because (as Patrick noted) sending plaintext passwords was quite concerning to a lot of folks.
Documentation for the function is at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/

As of WP 4.9, it is also possible to change the email sent to the user with the wp_new_user_notification_email filter.

But, if a plugin is overriding wp_new_user_notification, then that's a moot point, and you need to either override it yourself (by copying the code from core), or by asking the plugin developer responsible to fix their outdated code.